# 3000 new contacts being added to gmail after receiving an email

Tags: email, attack-prevention, google

Recently I realized that there are three thousand contacts with same name and email address in my Google contacts. The name belongs to an email that I have recently received and responded to, nothing special existed about the email.

Could this be an attack or simply a bug in the services which I use? I use my android smartphone synced with my account as well as gmail itself.

Comment: Could we see a screenshot of the problem? There are a number of ways Google populates your contacts - your Google+ circles, people you reply to, etc.

Comment: I have deleted them, but I got this in gmail contact search and my android phone as well. Is seems more a software problem in android or google mail itself. @scuzzy-delta

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that, as a hacker wouldn't, to my knowledge, benefit from this at all (unless it is some kind of attack meant to overload a process??? seems unlikely...) this is almost certainly just a glitch. By default, Google usually adds anyone you respond to to your contacts; in all likelihood it just had a minor glitch. If the hacker thought you would not know how to remove contacts en masse he might have thought to exasperate you and make you decide just to leave the contacts there after a few hundred deletes. I think e-mail from contacts goes to your inbox automatically, even if it does not pass spam filters, so it might have simply been phase one of a spamming scheme? Maybe check your spam periodically to see if there is anything in there from this address - just out of interest.

Comment: I think this is not because of that email, since recently I found another contact which is duplicated about 25000 times! So either this is a bug in Google services or more likely it is because of a complicated bug caused of using multiple devices and applications to access my Google contacts.